# producer to multiple threads consumer queue in C

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, queue, producer-consumer

I'm trying to `backup()` all files and sub-directory files as they are found simultaneously using multiple threads in C (not C++, meant for Windows).

```
// pseudocode for the backup function and loop

int backup(char *filename) {
     // compress
     // move to backup drive
    
     ...

     if(success) return 1;
     return 0;
}

void recursive_file_scan(char *base_path) {
     ...

     if(is_folder(file_path)) 
          recursive_file_scan(file_path);
     ...
     ...

     // next file in line
     char *filename = file_path;

     /*
      *  send filename to next available thread for backup()
      *  then continue the recursive_file_scan()
      *  without waiting for the last thread to finish first
      */
}
```

With 4 threads to work off of the `recursive_file_scan()`, how do I create a a queue to pass the next `*filename` to the next available thread without waiting for the last thread to finish, while also allowing the other threads to continue and grab the next filename when they're ready?

The goal is speed, so no repeated/duplicate files or lag that would slow down the `recursive_file_scan()` loop.

Comment: You can `detach` the thread after passing the `filename` and recursively loop find next file and `detach` again. If memory is not limited then it won't cause any issue.

Comment: *I'm trying to `backup()` all files and sub-directory files as they are found simultaneously using multiple threads ... The goal is speed*  That will probably be **slower** than using a single thread unless your source and destination disk system(s) are designed for parallel reading and writing.

Comment: @AndrewHenle could you elaborate? if there is one loop finding files and sending them to multiple designated threads for backing up, how would it be _slower_ than backing the files up as they appear during the loop?

Comment: The multiple threads will likely be contending for access to the same storage devices.  If the storage devices are spinning disks, that will cause the disk heads to have to do a lot more seeking than they would if they could, for example, just stream the contents of a single file one-after-another  Each time you make a spinning disk seek to a new track, that usually takes 5-20 milliseconds, with fast 15K SAS drives at the lower end of that.  Normal consumer SATA drives are normally going to be in the 15-20 ms range.

Comment: would it still be an issue if instead, it created a thread for each individual drive (C:/, D:/, Z:/, etc)? That way, none of them are competing with a producer thread and each have their own recursive loop on a separate file system or mounted device like a USB.